# Find the solution of $z=pq$ by Charpit's method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving the question $$z = pq$$

I have formed this auxiliary equation: $$ {dx\over -q} + {dy\over p} + {dz\over 2pq } + {dp\over p} + {dx\over q}$$

I have used $${dp\over p}={dq\over q}$$ I got $$p=aq$$

I put this in $$z = pq$$ then $$q = {\sqrt\frac za}$$ then $$p = \sqrt(az)$$

after putting in $$dz = pdx + qdy$$

I got soln as $$\sqrt a . 2\sqrt z = ax + y + b $$ but the answer key is saying $$2\sqrt z= ax + \frac ya + b $$

Comment: Your solution is equivalent to the answer key.

Comment: Okay so it was just putting another constant, I was so dumb that I could not recognise this small thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x,y,z,p,q)=pq-z
$$
using Charpit's method:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x } +p\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial z } }=\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial y } +q\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial z } }=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{-p\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial p } -q\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial q } }=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{-\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial p } }=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial q } }
$$
And,
$$
\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x } =0;\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial y } =0;\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial z } =-1;\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial p } =q;\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial q } =p
$$
So,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{p}=\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{q}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2pq}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{q}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{p}
$$

Integrating the first two terms as you say:
$$
p=C_{1}q
$$
Put it into the equation
$$
z=C_{1}q^{2}
$$
$$
q=\sqrt{ \frac{z}{C_{1}} };p=\sqrt{ C_{1}z }
$$
$$
\mathrm{d}z=p\mathrm{d}x+q\mathrm{d}y
$$
So,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{ z }}=\sqrt{ C_{1} }\mathrm{d}x+\sqrt{ \frac{1}{C_{1}} }\mathrm{d}y
$$
If let $\sqrt{ C_{1} }=a$, and integrating
$$
2\sqrt{ z }=ax+\frac{y}{a}+b
$$